# How can I decode this utf-8 string, picked on a random website and saved by the Django ORM, using Python?

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8

I parsed a file and saved its content in a database using Django. The website was 100% in English, so I naively assumed it would be ASCII all along, and saved the text happily as unicode.

You guess the rest of the story :-)

When I print, I get the usual encoding error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 48: ordinal not in range(128)
```

A quick search tells me that u'\u2019' is the UTF-8 representation of `’`.

`repr(string)` displays me this:

```
"u'his son\\u2019s friend'"
```

Then of course I tried `django.utils.encoding.smart_str` and a more direct approach using string.encode('utf-8'), and I ended up with something printable. Unfortunatly, it prints  like this in my (linux UTF-8) terminal:

```
In [76]: repr(string.encode('utf-8'))
Out[76]: "'his son\\xe2\\x80\\x99s friend '"

In [77]: print string.encode('utf-8')
his son�s friend
```

Not what I expected. I suspect I double encoded something or missed an important point.

Of course the file original encoding is not pusblished with the file. I guess I could read the HTTP headers or ask the webmaster but since \u2019s looks like UTF-8, I assumed it was utf-8. I can be very wrong, tell me if I am.

Solutions obviously appreciated, but a deep explanation on the cause and what to do to avoid this to happen again would be even more. I often get bitten with encoding, which shows that I still don't master completly the subject.

Comment: Programs like MS Word change the quotation marks (and apostrophes) to non-ascii values. Probably the user copied and pasted the data

Comment: It works for me. What terminal are you using? you might not have the right glyph in your font.

Comment: BTW, the u2019 is the RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK code point, not the UTF-8 representation.

Comment: I'm using Gnome-Terminal on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are fine.  You have the proper data.  Yes, the original data is UTF-8 (based on context u2019 makes perfect sense as an apostrophe between "son" and "s"). The weird `?` error character probably just means your terminal configuration's font doesn't have a glyph for this character (fancy apostrophe). No big deal.  The data will be correct where it counts. If you are nervous, try some different terminal/OS combinations (I'm on OS X using iTerm).  I spent a lot of time explaining to my QA guys that the scary `?` question mark character just means they don't have a Chinese font installed on their windows box (In my case we were testing with Chinese data).  Here's some comments

```
#Create a Python Unicode object
#(abstract code points, independent of any encoding)
#single backslash tells python we want to represent
#a code point by its unicode code point number, typed out with ASCII numbers
>>> s1 = u'his son\u2019s friend'

#If you just type it at the prompt,
#the interpreter does the equivalent of `print repr(s1)`
#and since repr means "show it like a string typed into a python source file",
#you get your ASCII escaped version back
>>> s1
u'his son\u2019s friend'
>>> print repr(s1)
u'his son\u2019s friend'

#This isn't ASCII, so encoding into ASCII generates your original
#error as expected
>>> s1.encode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character
 u'\u2019' in position 7: 
ordinal not in range(128)

# Encode in UTF-8 and now we have a string,
# which gets displayed as hex escapes.     
#Unicode code point 2019 looks like it gets 3 bytes in UTF-8 (yup, it does)
>>> s1.encode('utf-8')
'his son\xe2\x80\x99s friend'

#My terminal DOES have a different glyph (symbol) to use here,
#so it displays OK for me.
#Note that my terminal has a different glyph for a normal ASCII apostrophe
#(straight vertical)
>>> print s1
his son’s friend
>>> repr(s1)
"u'his son\\u2019s friend'"
>>> str(s1.encode('utf-8'))
'his son\xe2\x80\x99s friend'
```

See also: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html

See also for character 2019 (e28099 in hex, search for "2019" on this page): http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8000

See also: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Thanks Peter. I had so many troubles with encoding I just assumed I did something wrong :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am being naïve, but... isn't your problem just with having escaped the leading `\` of the unicode code point?

Your original string behaves like:

```
>>> s = u'his son\\u2019s friend'
>>> print(s)
his son\u2019s friend
```

But removing the escaping `\` gives:

```
>>> s = u'his son\u2019s friend'
>>> print(s)
his son’s friend
```

Comment: I didn't escape the "\", this is how it appears when you use 'repr' since repr escape everything to allow you to copy past the data in a terminal.

Comment: @e-satis - Then the question is the one Keith made in the comments... what python version / OS / installation are you using? Mine is a vanilla Python 2.7.1 on an ubuntu 11.04 64bit machine.

Comment: vanilla Python 2.7.1 on an ubuntu 11.04 32bit :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try invoking a python shell like this:

```
python2 -S -i -c 'import sys;sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8");import site'
```

Then:

```
>>> s = u'his son\u2019s friend'
>>> print s.encode("utf-8")
his son’s friend
```

Then the default encoding is utf-8 and it should print fine.

Comment: `$ python2 -S -i -c 'import sys;sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8");import site'
>>> s = u'his son\u2019s friend'
>>> print s.encode("utf-8")
his son�s friend` :-(

Comment: Anyway, +1 for the python snippet